# Reference to inner index?

Tags: c++, vector, reference

Suppose I have

```
vector<vector<int> > a;
```

which is indexed as

```
a[i][j] = stuff;
```

where i is "outer" and j is "inner"...

Then creating a reference to the "outer" vector is easy:

```
vector<int>& b = a[x];
```

Is there a nice way to create a reference to the inner?

```
vector<int>& b = a[<don't know>][x];
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question. `a` is the outer vector, so `a[x]` accesses one of the inner vectors (there isn't just one inner vector, since you've defined a vector of vectors). One level further down, you get to individual integers.

Comment: The question is confusing. How can you make a reference of int into vector<int>.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, there's no direct way of creating a reference like that because the compiler is treating this like

```
a.operator[] (/* ... don't know ... */).operator[] (x);
```

This only makes sense if the first call to `operator []` actually hands back a `vector`.

However, what you can do is fake this behavior by introducing a new class that specifically handles the behavior.  The idea is to have this class store the second index and provide an `operator[]` function that, given the first index, looks up the real value in the `vector`.  Here's one example:

```
class IndexReverser { // Or, your favorite name
public:
    IndexReverser(vector< vector<int> >& v, size_t index);

    int& operator[] (size_t firstIndex);

private:
    vector< vector<int> >& realVector;
    const size_t secondIndex;
};

IndexReverser::IndexReverser(vector< vector<int> >&v,
                             size_t index) : realVector(v), secondIndex(index) {
    // Handled in initialization list
}
int& IndexReverser::operator[] (size_t firstIndex) {
    return realVector[firstIndex][secondIndex];
}
```

You could then write, for example, this:

```
IndexReverser ir(a, j);
ir[i] = 137;
```

You might need to provide a twin class to handle `const` vectors, and probably would want to parameterize the entire structure on the type of the elements being stored.  I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it least shows that in principle you can get the behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question.  I'll write the templatized version of your IndexReverser class.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
vector<int>& b = a[x];
```

is not a reference to the outer vector but rather one of the inner vectors. Also note that there are possible many inner vectors.

Here's how to get a reference to the outer vector (although in general it would be pointless):

```
vector<vector<int> > &outer = a;
```

Getting a reference to one of the inner vectors looks something like this:

```
vector<int> &inner = a[x];
```